# When clicking on the Forgot password link of a service provider oauth2 login, the user is redirected to the Carbon login page

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When clicking on the Forgot password link of a service provider login page, the user is redirected to the Carbon login page, this should not happen, as the user only have to login via the provider page, not via Carbon.

[image]

[image]

Most important, if I proceed with the login on Carbon, a 405 Method Not Allowed page is shown

[image]

**Detailed Github Issue:**

https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7762

**Product version:**

WSO2 API Manager 2.6

Answer (score 0):

On WSO2 Identity Server 5.7 (compatible with APIM 2.6) this feature works, so I will proceed by using that instead as identity provider, since this functionality is simply missing from 2.6 and below (which works on v3.0 btw).